# which offline bootstrap files we need and which one is we don't?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have downloaded the bootstrap but i'm curious which files we need and which one is we don't? I'm working on it but curious can anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the layout you only need `bootstrap.min.css` from the css folder.

If you planning to use modal or any components which uses jquery you need to import `bootstrap.min.js` from the js folder and also latest `jquery` and `popper.js` from [here](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Remember to include the scripts in the right order: jQuery first, then Popper.js and **lastly** `bootstrap.min.js`. If you aren't going to use a package manager, you can grab the links from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).